# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS + Maven 3 + Java 11

Tags: java, 20.04, maven-3

I have a fresh new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on my machine.

I also installed Maven (Apache Maven 3.6.3) and Java (openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14)

If I download now for testing the [Spring Boot Demo project](https://start.spring.io/) I always got the error:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 mvn spring-boot:run -X
```

[image]

It works on every other computer perfectly, just not on the new one.
I searched a lot but I haven't found any solution for this problem...

Comment: You shouldn't be getting those Warnings in the first place. How did you install Java and Maven? Did you download the demo project without adding any dependency? Since I also use JDK 11 and Maven 3.6.3, [these](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jfMWSYdkhC/) are my logs.

Comment: It works on every other computer perfectly, just not on the new one. (added this now to the original).  Just on the Ubuntu 20 I  have this problem.
I downloaded maven with `sudo apt install maven`  and java with `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-source`

Comment: I actually use maven from apache's site instead of APT. Interestingly `guice.jar` doesn't exist in my installation. Try installing from Apache's site. If you need help in installation, I have added commands that are to be run in a [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RxKFFPRG2w/). Once you're done, logout of the current session or reboot the device. Try running `mvn` and the project again.

Comment: I have done this stuff many times, it always worked. Just not this time. strange. I even reinstalled maven and Java and still the same problems.

Comment: @Kulfy I removed my maven and installed the one from apache - the warning is gone - the result is unfortunately is the same.

Comment: @Kulfy - i always prefer running my apps from the shell. that's not the problem.

Comment: It seems the process is being killed by the shell. Do you see any logs related to mvn in `dmesg` and `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: both show nothing...

Comment: What about `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: ... It can't be that some "security feature" of our company is the reason... looking to it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason was a "security feature" (shitty traps) from the company I work for. If you are not connected to the VPN, it will have this strange stuff going on.
Thanks Kulfy for the help!